# What is the reason to initialize or assign an empty string literal to a pointer to char in C, or a pointer to const char in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, string-literals

My question is actually quite simply for those who might know about it, but I ask because I'm not aware of this technique already.

What is the reason for initializing or assigning an empty string literal to a pointer to `char` in C, or a pointer to `const char` in C++?

Like f.e.:

```
char* p = "";
```

or

```
char* p;
p = "";
```

---

Or, as suggested in the comments, in C++:

```
const char* p = "";
```

or

```
const char* p;
p = "";
```

---

I do often see this technique, but don't understand why someone shall assign an empty string literal to a `char` pointer (or pointer to `const char` for C++) or where this is coming from.

---

I have read [Initialize a string in C to empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142745), but this question is focused on initializing a `char` array with an empty string.

And I have also read: [Initializing a string with the empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467366/), but this question covers an incorrect approach to assign an empty string to a pointer earlier returned by a `malloc()` function.

Comment: Can you put it into some context?

Comment: I can think of no reason to initialize a pointer intended on referring to mutable data to *any* string literal, be it an empty string or otherwise.

Comment: @klutt The last time I´ve seen it was on this question earlier made today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276712/function-running-when-it-shouldnt by `root.value = "";` inside of `main` with `char *value;` inside of the `struct TreeNode`.

Comment: Your C++ compiler gives you a warning because the type of a string literal is `const char*` rather than `char*`.

Comment: @user3684240 So `const char *p = "";` would be permissible in C++?

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560060/is-char-pointer-address-initialization-necessary-in-c

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, that would work.

Comment: @user3684240 Ok, cool. thank you for the information. But the question remains, what the purpose of doing so is.

Comment: This is essentially the same category of question as asking why someone would set `char* p = NULL;`. That can't be answered, it completely depends on the context!

Comment: @Lundin In what for a context it would be appreciated to do?

Comment: Someone could set it to `""` to sate some particular function API, or it could serve as sentinel value in some array of strings etc etc. This is application-level stuff and the reason why will be on case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason to initialize or assign an empty string literal to a pointer to char in C or a pointer to const char in C++?

To me it seems that there is a misunderstanding here. The pointer is **not** initialized with an empty string. It is initialized to **point to** an empty string (a string literal that the compiler placed somewhere in memory). That's a major difference.

Consider this code:

```
char* p = "";
printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
p = "test";
printf("%p\n", (void*)p);
```

Possible output:

```
0x563e72497007
0x563e72497008
```

In these cases `p` holds a memory address where the compiler placed the two string literals (i.e. "" at 0x563e72497007 and "test" at 0x563e72497008). So in that memory you have:

```
0x563e72497007 '\0'                  (i.e. the empty string that only consists 
                                           a string termination character`)

0x563e72497008 't' 'e' 's' 't' '\0'  (i.e. the string "test")
```

So again - `p` is not initialized/assigned with the strings, it is initialized/assigned to **point to strings**.

Why would you want to initialize a pointer to point to an empty string?

Well, it's like any other variable that you initialize... You do it because you want the variable to have a known value in case it's used before any other assignment is made to it. So just like doing `int i = 0;`.

In other words - you do `char* p = "";` to make sure that `p` points to a valid C-style string.

A very simple example:

```
char* p = "";
if (answerIsWrong())
{
    p = "not";
}
printf("The answer is %s correct\n", p);
```

Depending on the return value from the function `answerIsWrong()` this may print:

```
The answer is correct
```

or

```
The answer is not correct
```

In the first case it's important the `p` was initialized to **point to** an empty string.

However, if you **know** that you'll never use `p` before it's assigned a new value, there is obviously no reason to initialize it! However, some programmers prefer to always initialize all variables - even if they assign another value before use.

Example:

```
char* p = "";  // No reason for this initialization
               // p will be assigned another value before it's used

if (answerIsWrong())
{
    p = " not ";
}
else
{
    p = " absolutely ";
}
printf("The answer is %s correct\n", p);
```

Comment: Is `""` equivalent to `NULL` in C or `nullptr` in C++?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio no... Try printing `p` like `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);` You'll **not** get NULL. You'll get the address of the empty string. As I wrote: "That's a major difference."

Comment: You said *"You do it because you want the variable to have a known value in case it's used before any other assignment is made to it. So just like doing int i = 0;."* - What is the value for `""`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio You ask: What is the value for "" Well, it's a 1 char long string and the value of the char is `'\0'` or so known as NUL (single L). In C all strings end with `'\0'`. Therefore it is also called the string termination character.

Comment: But the location of `p` in the memory is different with the string of `test` than with `""` in your example. Means, it occupies a different space. Why should I block space in memory when I´ll never use it? This also would make the initialization point of view useless, since it is another space.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio 1) Yes, "" and "test" occupies different location of memory. That's how string literals work. 2) If you **know** that you'll never use `p` before it's assigned a new value, there is obviously no reason to initialize it! However, some programmers prefer to **always** initialize **all variables** - even if they assign another value before use.

Comment: So it is almost a complete non-sense kind of thing? Just to have the "security" that when the pointer is accidentally used, you have a value and not going into UB? Interested.

Comment: You should take 1) - with the difference in the memory location and 2) as it is - directly into the question. That would be very helpful.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Correct. If you are **absolutely sure** that `p` is assigned another value before use then you can the initialization a "a complete non-sense kind of thing".

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Thanks for your edits. However notice that for `printf` it is just `p` - not `*p`

Comment: If you now add, that since they are string literals, you are pointing to other locations in memory and the first initialization of `""` does occupy never used memory when it is sure that `p` will get initialized to point to another string literal, I would accept this answer, because this is an important point to add, as opposed to other variable initializations, like the provided `int i = 0;`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on what follows. For example, the following would be acceptable:

```
const char *p = "";

if (f()) {
   p = "Foo";
}
else if (g())
   p = "Bar";
}

strcat(msg, p);
```

That said, this isn't a likely scenario. The value subsequently assigned to `p` is probably a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory which requires freeing, but `""` can't be freed, so you'd end up with

```
char *p = "";
int free_it = 0;

if (f()) {
   p = ff();
   free_it = 1;
}
else if (g())
   p = gg();
   free_it = 1;
}

strcat(msg, p);
if (free_it)
   free(p);
```

when you could just as easily to

```
char *p = NULL;

if (f()) {
   p = ff();
}
else if (g())
   p = gg();
}

if (p)
   strcat(msg, p);

free(p);
```

---

The approach taken in the [question you linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60276712/589924) leads to an inability to free the values. It would make more sense to have a node allocator and a node destructor.

```
int Node_init(Node *node, const char *value) {
    char *value_ = strdup(value);
    if (!value_)
       return 0;

    node->value = value_;
    node->sibling = NULL;
    node->child = NULL;
    return 1;
}

Node *Node_new(const char *value) {
   Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   if (!node) {
      return NULL;
   }

   if (!Node_init(node, value)) {
      free(node);
      return NULL;
   }

   return node;
}

void Node_destroy(Node *node) {
    free(node->value);
}

void Node_delete(Node *node) {
   Node_destroy(node);
   free(node);
}

int main(void) {
   Node root;
   Node_init(&root, "");
   ...
   Node_destroy(&root);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't necessarily go as far as to say that this is some kind of “coding technique”. Rather, I think that, in many cases, it is simply better than the alternatives.

Initializing to `""` may sometimes be preferred because it is more safe. Let's suppose you have code like this:

```
const char* s;
if(some_condition) {
  s = something();
} else if(some_other_condition) {
  s = something_else();
}
for(const char* p = s; *p; ++p) {
  /* do something */
}
```

Now, suppose you know with 95% certainty that either `some_condition` or `some_other_condition` will be true all the time, but this kind of code still looks scary to you (it does to me).

If you do not initialize `s` at all and none of conditions are true, the behaviour of your program is undefined. It may crash, it may not. You will never be able to check for the error condition later because `s` could be literally anything.

If you initialize `s` with `NULL`, you can now check for the error condition but your `for` loop still contains UB.

The safest way here would obviously be to include something like `else { assert(0); }` and explicitly check for the error condition, but if that's not necessary in your situation, you can initialize `s` to `""` and the code will just do nothing if `some_condition` and `some_other_condition` are both false.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *p = "";
```

Yields a valid null-terminated string (representing an empty string). Hence it may be used in functions accepting *c-style* strings, etc.

This is different from eg.:

```
const char *p = nullptr;
```

Which isn't a valid string, and will fail in most functions accepting c-style strings (eg. `std::string(nullptr)` will yield UB, a crash most likely).

I wouldn't call it a programming technique.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a a char pointer with an empty string literal does have the advantage, that in fact an empty string literal is not "empty". If you create a dummy program and look at `char* p = "";` with a debugger you will see, that an char array with length 1, containing `\0` is created. This means that `p` is pointing to a valid zero terminated string. Therefore you are able to pass p to most functions working with zero terminated strings (e.g. basically all standard library string manipulation functions) without having to worry about them failing/memory errors etc. This is usefull, for example in a case where you are assining some value to `p` that depends on some condition that might fail, leaving you with a potential undefined behaviour, if you did not initialize the pointer with a proper value.

On that last note, there is also the issue of some coding standards forbidding uninitialised variables, as those are potential sources of bugs.

Comment: Add some tags (such as C or C++) your question will get more visibility :)

Comment: Re "*On that last note, there is also the issue of some coding standards forbidding uninitialised variables, as those are potential sources of bugs.*", So initialize it to `NULL`.